# Can't visualize the boundaries after OpenCV Watershed segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, bounding-box

I want to get the bounding boxes of the objects in this image. [image]

So I did a watershed segmentation according to [OpenCV watershed](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html):

```
# Finding unknown region
sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg,sure_fg)

# Marker labelling
ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)

# Add one to all labels so that sure background is not 0, but 1
markers = markers+1
# Now, mark the region of unknown with zero
markers[unknown==255] = 0

markers = cv2.watershed(im,markers)

"""Assign the markers a hue between 0 and 179"""
hue_markers = np.uint8(179*np.float32(markers)/np.max(markers))
blank_channel = 255*np.ones((h, w), dtype=np.uint8)
marker_img = cv2.merge([hue_markers, blank_channel, blank_channel])
marker_img = cv2.cvtColor(marker_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)


"""create image black background, white boundaries for contour detections"""
boundaries = np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.uint8)

boundaries[markers == -1] = 255
```

followed by a `cv2.findContours()`

```
ii, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(boundaries, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

output_im[markers == -1] = (0,255,0)
```

I do get (some of) the objects and the boundaries are shown, but only the whole image as a contour is found.

[image: marker_img] [image: output_im][image: boundaries]

Please don't mind the missing objects, i want to fix that by tweaking the segmentation parameters later.

Comment: `watershed` creates a 1 pixel wise line of `-1` all around the image. You need to remove / ignore that to get the inner (actual) contours

Comment: I don't think there is a need to watershed the image. [I just threshold the blue channel, find the external contours, then get the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98pSN.png)